# row action based on row data in react material-table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I need to have a row action only in certain rows (with particular property values). For example, if I have a row that has the property `isDeletable` set to true, I would like to be able to delete it, i.e have a delete icon present in the actions column.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [actions](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/actions) definitions of your `MaterialTable` component, you can access to `rowData` parameter which you can be used to conditionally calculate the `disabled` or `hidden` props of each action. Check the following example where the action enabled only when `status ==='active'`.

```js
<MaterialTable
// ..other props
actions={[
          (rowData) => {
            return {
              icon: "bug_report",
              tooltip: "Report bug",
              disabled: rowData.status === "active",
              // hidden: rowData.status === "active",
              onClick: (event, rowData) =>
                alert("This client status is " + rowData.status)
            };
          }
        ]}
/>
```

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-conditionally-disable-or-hide-actions-oc9f1?file=/src/App.js) whit a working example.

Let me know if that worked for you!