# Material table : Select + action with rowData

Tags: reactjs, action, selection, material-table

I have an issue with Material-Table, perhaps you can find a solution or maybe a workaround will be the match.
The version I'm using is 1.69.3 as it is the most stable one (I got some issues using the lastest version).
I'm trying to add a "edit" feature depending on the information of the row.
Let me kindly add below an screenshot of what I'm talking about:
[image: table]
Only when the last column has a "No Informado" as a value, the EDIT button should be showed. If not, no button will be the result.
(sorry for spanish in the table)

I've looked for some potential solutions but all of them advices me to use the "rowData" in actions component, I've tried it but it only works if I don't use the selection option:

Working example without the selection option:

[image: Table without selection option]

[image]
[image]

I've also found a sandbox to make it easier to try.
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-conditionally-disable-or-hide-actions-forked-3humh0?file=/src/App.js
(this is a forked project, the real one was: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-conditionally-disable-or-hide-actions-oc9f1?file=/src/App.js
[row action based on row data in react material-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477091/row-action-based-on-row-data-in-react-material-table)
Credits for NicoE)

In this codesandbox if you uncomment this line, is exactly what I'm trying to do. Selectable table plus editable with rowData information in each row:
[image]

Thank you so much in advance,
Best regards everyone!,
Alejandro

Comment: If anyone is also with this issue, I needed to copy HeaderTable and RowTable from material table src code and use this new components editing the render options.